# Unexpected behavior after deleting a pointer in a vector

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

I was experimenting with vectors of pointers and came across the following behavior which I don't quite understand:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int*> vec;

    int* p1 = new int;
    *p1 = 100;

    vec.push_back(p1);  
    std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl;

    delete p1;
    std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl;

    int* p2 = new int;
    *p2 = 200;

    std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Using the MinGW C++ compiler (g++), this gave me the following output:

```
100
5640648
200
```

Now of course the actual element `vec[0]` was not erased when deleting the pointer, but note that `p2` is not inserted in the vector at all. Still, printing the value of the first element returns the value of this seemingly unrelated pointer! Also, restructuring the code a little bit so that `p2` is declared before deleting `p1` does not yield this behavior.

Just to make sure, I also compiled this with MSVC++, which gave me the following (expected) output:

```
100
5484120
5484120
```

Does anyone have an explanation for the first output?

Comment: Why is this behaviour unexpected? You do something that is undefined, after all :) The different outputs are likely related to the way the compilers map the memory. Did you compare the bytecodes?

Comment: This question is somewhat useful if only because it shows at the end of the day, its machine code that sometimes does interesting things if you do blatant, variable-boundary-jumping stuff at the language level.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It reallocated the space held by `p1`, which `vec[0]` was still pointing to, hence the `200` value that showed up.

As you have noticed, this was the behavior of one compiler, and another compiler acted differently.  You may have other behaviors based on different optimization switches as well.  So overall, the behavior is undefined, though we can sometimes figure out what happened in particular cases.

Comment: Do you mean that in the sense that the address of `p1` and the address of `p2` are equal? Because that does not seem to be the case when I look at them. If `p2` actually replaced `p1` at the same location in memory then the 200 value would make sense to me.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was thinking.  Since there's a vector involved, there might be another level of indirection in there somewhere.  How could it have replaced it?  You didn't do another pushback.

Comment: Accept this answer if you like it.

Comment: @Jim always give this link. syntax is: `[text to displace](url of link)`

Answer (score 6):

because after delete you access the memory it causes undefined behavior:

```
delete p1;
std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl;  <-- Buggy code
```

undefined behavior: - No guaranty how it will work

Comment: Fair enough. But then why is it that if `p2` would be declared before invoking `delete p1` the value of `*vec[0]` becomes something different? Something must be going on behind the scenes that causes the undefined behavior to change for both cases.

Comment: @mhj Undefined behavior means we can predict how program will behave at run time, declaring `p2` before `delete p1` doesn't make sense just code behaving differently because different sequences of  instructions at low level. The problem is you can't access a memory the is deleted that I marked buggy code in your program.

Comment: @mhj after `delete p1;` if you accesses the memory location, it will be a memory access violation that may be detected by runtime system an cause terminate your program.

Comment: This isn't really an explanation of why the first instance happened.  It is more of a (correct) statement that no explanation is required, as it is undefined behavior.

Comment: @Jim  Yes! as I said earlier also I don't explain much after undefined   behavior -- it confuses newbie. If I explained that `vec[0]` pointing to same location that is still not flushed then we would except same behavior with other compiler.

Comment: I see your point.  I think it is still quasi interesting as a 'what happened in this case' as it reveals the inner workings.

Comment: @Jim you have nice concepts I noticed many times, but OP is probably new guy. besides votes on SO are not justified. recently I given a good answer and explained about internal details of optimization but I was down-voted :( and I have to delete. And yes Its very interesting to explain what happen internally but you explained in only one line. that is incomplete in my eyes for OP. at-least you should add that "it will not be a case for always". For me your answer is good.

Comment: @mhj then Jim's answer is good! I would be glad if you accept his answer :) he also updated.

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan, I expanded my answer a bit.

Comment: @Jim Yes I have checked. Good Answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do you understand why this is **undefined behaviour** in the first place?

The value of `vec[0]` *is* `p1`. As soon as you delete p1; it becomes illegal to dereference vec[0]. vec[0] is just a copy of your pointer p1.

Imagine that the value of `p1` is (the address) 953241, which is returned by new for you to use freely. The int value that you store in that address is 100. But once you delete p1, you renounce to any rights concerning that address. You effectively give it back to the system. You *can't* read from it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you `delete p1`, C++ frees up the space that `p1` was taking up on the heap and lets it be used for other data.  So when you create `p2`, it puts it there because it's the next spot in memory it wants to use.

`vec[0]` still points there only because the data from your pointer is still there on the stack.  (C++ doesn't know you deleted the pointer was there, but the pointer data doesn't go anywhere, so you can sill access it.  It'll be replaced the next time you do anything on the stack.)

I'm guessing that MSVC++ purposefully tries not to use recently freed memory space because it's "safer" - if you `deleted` something by accident and then overwrote it, it's gone forever.

Answer (score 0):

```
delete p1;
std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl; // (1.)

int* p2 = new int;
*p2 = 200;

std::cout << *vec[0] << std::endl; // (2.)

return 0;
```

1. you deleted the memory so it is not defined what will be at this address.
2. in the `g++` output you see that the new value 200 is displayed, this is because it is at the adress of the

   ```
   int* p1 = new int;
   *p1 = 100;
   ```

   code, don't use the value because the behavior is implemention specific and it shows only up because you don't allocate anything earlier that can fit in the freed memory place.